# Running a series commands non-synchronously from a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subprocess

So here is my situation: I am calling a .bat file from a python script. I'm not sure if it's important, but I run the file with the python module subprocess. i.e.

```
subprocess.call("dir/file.bat", shell=True)
```

The .bat file creation is dependent on the user input during the python script execution, but generally it will contain ~30-40 lines of commands to run in cmd. All these lines of code are the exact same except for the input and output files for the command. For example:

```
start /wait metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText1.txt pradaxa1.out.txt
start /wait metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText2.txt pradaxa2.out.txt
start /wait metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText3.txt pradaxa3.out.txt
```

If I invoke metamap13 40 times simultaneously, my computer will crash because it is so memory-intensive. As you see, I have tried the

```
start /wait
```

combo so that the first line will finish before the second begins. Unfortunately, when the .bat file is executed, it opens a new window and once the program is finished running, the window does NOT close and therefore the second line does not begin until I manually close the new cmd window. The sheer amount of data that will be processed through this method means that I cannot always be available to close the hundreds of new windows. I have also tried the following:

```
start /wait /B metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText1.txt pradaxa1.out.txt
```

I thought the /B would remove the problem with having to close the window, but it still launches all 40 lines of code simultaneously. I think this has to do with the fact that calling metamap13 is considered a completed command and so it moves to the next line, even though metamap is actually still running. So I have thought of two possible solutions that I can't figure out how to implement:

1. Automate the closing of the new cmd windows once metamap13 has finished running.
2. Only run the next line once metamap13 has completed.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is metamap13 an exe? Have you tried running something like `start /wait "metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText1.txt pradaxa1.out.txt
"`

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/start.html also says that you should provide a title, or at least `""` for empty. It also offer samples in the form `START "" /wait [options] "C:\Program.exe" "-a ParametersInfo"`

Comment: could you try to replace your start commands with `cmd /C metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText1.txt pradaxa1.out.txt`

Comment: @PsychoData, the file being run has the extension: .x86-win32-nt-4
I'm not sure what that is, but I don't think it's an exe. The addition of the "" after START also don't help.

Comment: It's weird; I thought `start /wait` should have done the trick. Call waits for it to finish and then moves on though?

Comment: That's a good question for @foxidrive, but it seems like call waits for the batch program AND the called program to complete, whereas start /wait is just the batch command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The processes being launched in the `metamap13` batch file are involved here too, but try this to start with:

```
call metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText1.txt pradaxa1.out.txt
call metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText2.txt pradaxa2.out.txt
call metamap13 -Aq pradaxaText3.txt pradaxa3.out.txt
```